# Different redeemScript for the same scriptPubKey?

Tags: bitcoin-core, script, bitcoin-core-development, input-script

Most transaction outputs to P2SH addresses have the following scriptPubKey:

```
HASH160 f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04 OP_EQUAL
```

As I understand it, this transaction do not need to be signed. Is it true?

The user just needs to provide a redeemScript whose HASH160 is equal to f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04.

So, if we know that:

```
HASH160(data1) = hash1
HASH160(data2) = hash2
```

and the user creates two transaction outputs to P2SH addresses with the scriptPubKeys:

```
HASH160 f45d94733d430261962932e0c847075195916a04 OP_EQUAL
```

then the scriptPubKey is the same for both transaction outputs, but why is the redeemScript is always different?

```
HASH160(data1) = hash1
HASH160(data2) = hash1
....
????
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of two different redeem scripts with the same hash?

Answer (score 1):

A `P2SH` transaction will execute whatever `redeemScript` you provide, which must be a standard transaction:

> Transactions that redeem these pay-to-script outpoints are only
>   considered standard if the serialized script - also referred to as the
>   redeemScript - is, itself, one of the other standard transaction
>   types. See [BIP16](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki#specification)

Those standard transactions, like a `P2PKH` does require a signature, so even though you provide the right `redeemScript`, if it doesn't execute successfully, the entire tx will become invalid.

Comment: Just to note, Bitcoin Core 0.10.0 and later no longer require that the redeemScript is one of the standard transaction types. See https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/4365.